# Is it easy to port TortoiseHg to use Git instead?

Tags: windows, git, mercurial, tortoisehg, tortoisegit

TortoiseHg is superior to TortoiseGit in many features.
Would be a matter of changing a few lines of code to make a new TortoiseGit based on TortoiseHg, or it requires weeks/months of development?

Comment: It would have to be rewritten from scratch, not viable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would definitely not be just a matter of changing a few lines.

TortoiseHg is intimately written against Mercurial. It doesn't just wrap around the command line client, it integrates with the core python code.

The entire program, from bottom and up, would have to be rewritten.

It is much more constructive to give the TortoiseGit team good feedback on what you would like see improved.

Comment: If only Mercurial-Svn plugin had support for auto properties, I could.

Comment: The problem is, TGit doesn't just have missing features or bugs that can be fixed, it is fundamentally flawed. This is still true even 3 years after this post. TGit is modeled closely after its elder namesake TortoiseSVN (and indeed even uses some of its source as its base). The resulting workflow just doesn't work out well with a DVCS. It makes switching from centralized VCS to DVCS harder rather than easier by pretending that there isn't much difference between them and no need to change your way of thinking. THg on the other hand is built around DVCS workflows from ground up.

Answer (score 9):

You can use Mercurial with Git repositories via the excellent [hg-git extension](http://hg-git.github.com/), which is developed by the github folks.  Any recent TortoiseHg version already has the dulwich library, you just need to clone hg-git and add a couple lines to your mercurial.ini file.

The instructions are in the TortoiseHg help under ["Use with other VCS systems"](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.10/nonhg.html#hg-git-git) .

Directions for configuring ssh can be found [here](http://www.codza.com/mercurial-with-ssh-setup-on-windows).  However, TortoiseHg will automatically use the plink it comes bundled with, so you don't need to worry about configuring PuTTY's plink.

Note that I've had some problems cloning large repos on XP due to file locking issues which don't seem to occur on Windows 7.

Comment: +1 Great! I'm testing it. It didn't work with the GIT repository due to `git\brainf*ck.bf: Incorrect file syntax`. probably a Windows limitation, I don't know how the git client would handle this

Comment: Really, a file with an asterisk in the name?  I hate to be sarcastic but what genius thought of that one! lol

Comment: @CADbloke, that link has died :( is this what you were referring to? http://jamesmckay.net/2010/06/tortoisehg-as-a-github-client-on-windows/

Comment: @SamHasler Yes, that's the one. He wiped his blog for a little while but seems to have re-instated it, thank $Deity. I'm waiting to see if Phil Haack releases his Github windows client soon, otherwise I'm just going to install the usual suspects for Git.